# Mysql update query not updating all the specified columns

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have php page called `update_products.php`, When i run this page below update query will execute. I am able to print this query on browser with out any errors.

But on database only `Qty` column is updated not remaining all columns in the query. But when i run this query through phpmyadmin all columns updated successfully.

`Qty,Original,Requested,Requested` these 4 column data type is `float`. Even i changed `Qty = '101.00'` but still no use. MySQL server and Apache is running on windows machine.

```
UPDATE `products` set `Qty` = '101', `Original` = '103.00',
       `Requested` = '2.00', `Remaining` = '101', 
       `Delivery_date` = '10-Jul-2014',`inserted_on_1` = now(),
       `round_status` = 'R1_DONE' 
       WHERE `pid` = '4046228004761' AND `catid` = '100'
```

Please help me out in this regard. Thanks.

Comment: If you can execute the query in MysqlAdmin without any problem, then the error must be in your php code, post it so we can take a look

Comment: AS you said if there is any error in my code i will not get the above values , and fyi this program is executing successfully on linux server.

Comment: If I were you, I'd use die; right after the query execution in php script to make sure there aren't other queries being executed afterwards.